# Why is this Factory causing a test to fail, when building the record manually passes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

In a Rails app I'm testing user confirmations

```
scenario "unconfirmed user cannot login" do
  user = create(:user, confirmation_sent_at: 10.days.ago ) #FactoryGirl factory
  login user
  expect(current_path).to eq(#unconfirmed_user_path)
end
```

This fails, and the user is signed in.

However if I change the first line as follows

```
user = create(:user)
user.confirmation_sent_at = 10.days.ago
user.save
login user .....
```

The test passes.

What am I overlooking? These two pieces of code are equivalent aren't they?

## EDIT

```
#factories/user_factory.rb

factory :user do
  email { Faker::Internet.email }
  password Faker::Internet.password(10, 20) 
end

# models/user.rb
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  confirmation_token     :string(255)
#  confirmed_at           :datetime
#  confirmation_sent_at   :datetime
#  ...

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  devise :invitable, :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable, :lockable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable

 ...
end
```

Comment: what happens when you call user.reload in the second version?  I am assuming you want the first test to fail?  I would think if the user logged in he would be on the confirmed user path.

Comment: For anyone to determine if the two are equivalent, they would need to see your FactoryGirl :user definition and your User model implementation.

Comment: @ruby_newbie the test should pass. An unconfirmed user should not be able to log in, and in fact this is the case when interacting with the app in a browser. however the test allows the user to log in, and while #unconfirmed_user_path is expected, #user_after_sign_in_path is returned.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin code added above. But in essence, including an attribute within the FactoryGirl create function (i.e., `create(:object, attribute: 'something'` ) is identical to creating the object and then setting the attribute (i.e., `object.attribute = 'something'`), isn't it?